# Disable boundingbox calculation for certain grouped object3Ds

Tags: three.js

I have several objects grouped in a Object3D. I wanna calculate the boundingbox of the whole group, except some specific objects in that group.

Can you disable the calculation of boundingbox for those objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mugen mentioned it's not possible to do this out of the box but you can achieve it by manually traversing the tree.

Here's an idea for how you might do that.

```
var box = null;

group.traverse(c => {

    // logic for whether or not to include the child
    var includeChild = c.isMesh;
    if (includeChild) {

        // initialize the box to the first valid child found
        // otherwise expand the bounds
        if (box === null) {

            box = new THREE.Box3();
            box.setFromObject(c);

        } else {

            box.expandByObject(c);

        }

    }

});
```

You can change the boolean logic for `includeChild` to determine whether or not you want an object to be included in the bounds calculations or not.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That looks awesome, gonna test it tomorrow! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Can you disable the calculation of boundingbox for those objects?

If you are using `Box3.setFromObject()` then no, this is not possible. The code processes all children of the hierarchy and expands the AABB if an object has a geometry property.

`three.js R101`